# Intellisense behavior

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

Not reporting it as a bug until I know if this is a feature or not and if there is any way to change the behavior.

Lets say I'm working on a file with some object and typing for example:

[image]

Lets say in this case I really want ul.insert. and none of the suggested ones on the list.

As soon as I press . (dot) the one highlighted on the list autocompletes.

I don't mind intellisense reacting and autocompleting when I press either Enter or TAB, but why is it triggering when I hit dot or ( for example.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

I know I can hit ESC to make the intellisense go away but it would make much more sense to me if it wouldn't autocomplete in the first place with . or (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable this setting:

`Editor: Accept Suggestion on Commit Character`

In javascript, the `.` is a "commit character".  Which means that the way the language server was set up a `.` would accept the selected suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. Didn't know that settings, looks like now it works as I was expecting.